# Angular ui pagination not working

Tags: angularjs, pagination

Can some one spot error with this pagination. Date in the table is not updating with change of page links

```
                <uib-pagination
                        ng-model="currentPage"
                        total-items="rows.length"
                        max-size="maxSize"
                        boundary-links="true">
                </uib-pagination>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1XPI7zwSrooBeAcBNddU?p=preview

Comment: You haven't posted enough code ***in the question itself*** to really understand or reproduce your problem.  however, just a quick glance at your linked plunker shows that you are using a different `ng-model` for your pagination control than for the table.

Comment: i did not understand what you said. "different ng-model"

Comment: your pagination is using `ng-model="currentPage"`, but your table is using `ng-model="filteredRows"`, so the pagination control will have no effect on that table.

Comment: i have a $watch method that changes filteredrows basing on currentPage selection

Comment: I don't think you need all the watch stuff ... see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could simplify your code a little ...
This should work:

HTML (just the diff):

```
<tr ng-repeat="reservation in rows | limitTo:numPerPage:(currentPage - 1) * numPerPage">
```

JS:

```
$scope.rows=[ ... ];
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 3;
$scope.maxSize = 5;
$scope.startAt = 0;
```